# mysql vs mysqli error when running php code in wamp stack

Tags: php

( mysql vs mysqli error (advait) )

Hi All, See code. This code runs on my localhost WAMP Win7 php ver 5.5.12 but it gives an error:

```
---
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\get_data02.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  135216  {main}( )   ..\get_data02.php:0
2   0.0010  135680  mysql_connect ( )   ..\get_data02.php:9
---
```

I tried replacing mysql with mysqli but that just gave more errors. How do I fix this? Thanks,

```
<?php
// 1. Enter Database details
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'iamdb_copy_04';
// 2. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
// 3. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE city = 'city' ");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
   $f_name = $rows['first_name'];
   $address_01 = $rows['address_01'];
   $city = $rows['city'];
   echo "$f_name<br>$address_01<br>$city<br><br>";      
} 
?>
```

Comment: You cannot simply do a string replacement from `mysql` to `mysqli` and expect everything to work. You need to port your code. Please take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php It comes with useful examples. Also you will find tutorials on the internet.

Comment: As an aside, when you run into deprecation problems your first port of call should usually be the official documentation for the language/library in question as it should tell you what the suggested replacement for the functionality should be and hopefully with implementation examples. Not saying you shouldn't have asked here just a good rule of thumb for the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to get out from this error.

1. Set `display_errors` off in php file using `ini_set("display_errors",0)` after start of php `<?php`.
2. Replace `mysql` with `mysqli` in `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db`,`mysql_query`, `mysql_fetch_array`.

Let me know if you still face any problem and also comment your error.